# How to exclude styles mentioned in angular.json for a particular component

Tags: angular

I have bootstrap `style.css` in `angular.json` styles. 
And I have another component where I have to exclude the `styles.css` from bootstrap and have to override it with the `sytleUrls` mentioned in the component.

Ps. I don't want any bootstrap styles for this component. How can I do this?

Comment: use View Encapsulation !!

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Thanks. It helped.